# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'signatures'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to use Tensorflow's Object Detection API with a pre-trained model. I'm loading the model with this:

```
model_name='fish_inception_v2_graph2'
PATH_TO_CKPT='models/research/object_detection/'+model_name+'/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

### Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_model = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

That seems to work fine but then the API has a section to "Check the model's input signature, it expects a batch of 3-color images of type uint8":

```
print(detection_model.signatures['serving_default'].inputs)
```

When I run that is when I get the error "AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'signatures'".

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, what you are trying to do here? Are you trying to perform inference on an image or trying to find input tensors or something? Because the error is right as the graph doesn't serve any signatures attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the path to the checkpoint just mention the model.ckpt-10000 or something of that sort. You are providing a .pb file and hence the error.